# undefined index and invalid foreach() argument php

Tags: php, forms, undefined-index

I have a page which shows items which users have saved to a MYSQL database, and echos it out along with a a check box. I would like when a user clicks this check box and clicks the save button that the record will be deleted but i am met with the errors in my title.

Show holidays form.

```
        <form action="deleteProcess.php">
<?php
        foreach($db->query($sql) as $row)
        {
            echo "<p>" . $row['title'] . "<br \>" . 
                         $row['description'] . "<br \>" . 
                         $row['link'] . "<br \>" .
                         $row['pubDate'] . 
                         "<input type='checkbox' name='del[]' value='$row/['title'/]'/>" . 
                         "</p>";    
        }
?>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="submit" />
        </form>
```

delete process.php

```
foreach($_POST['del'] as $check_value)
        {
            //takes session value and assigns it to a variable so that when a holiday is saved it can be distinguished by user
            $user = $_SESSION['name'];
            //assign the value of previous checkbox to $check
            $check = $check_value;
            //assign xpath query to variable $fav
            $fav = "channel/item [title = \"$check\"]";
            //loads instance of xml file as $holidayDoc
            $holidayDoc = simplexml_load_file('holidays.xml');
            //executes xpath search within holidays.xml and results stored in $favourites
            $favourites = $holidayDoc->xpath($fav);

        //for each element of the associative array $favourites, key will be referred to as $currentFav. 
        foreach($favourites as $currentFav)
        {
            echo "{$currentFav->link}". "<br \>";
            echo "{$currentFav->title}". "<br \>";
            echo "{$currentFav->description}". "<br \>";
            echo "{$currentFav->pubDate} ". "<br \>";
            //sql statement that states which values will be inserted into which column
            $sql = "DELETE FROM `saved_holidays` (`subscriberID`, `link`, `pubDate`, `title`, `description`) 
        VALUES ('$user', '$currentFav->link', '$currentFav->pubDate', '$currentFav->title', '$currentFav->description')";

            //connect to database then execute the sql statement.
            $db->exec($sql);
            //close connection to the database
            $db = null;
```

The error is showing at the `foreach($_POST['del'] as $check_value)` line and i cant understand why its not working, any help would be appreciated.

> Notice: Undefined index: del in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11026991/public_html/Ass/deleteProcess.php
>   on line 14
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11026991/public_html/Ass/deleteProcess.php
>   on line 14

Comment: Did you try a var_dump on $_POST? Is there any data? As it looks, the del index for $_POST isn't set which then would cause an invalid foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `del` checkboxes aren't being POSTed from the form at all. You need to add `method="post"` to your form.

`<form action="deleteProcess.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if $_POST['del'] is set because if no checkboxes are checked it won't be.

```
if(isset($_POST['del'])){
    foreach($_POST['del'] as $del){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You access your checkbox values via $_POST, but your Form-Tag has no method defined!
you have to set `<form method="POST">`, otherwise you have to use `$_GET['del']`

Answer (score 1):

`method="post"` is missing from `<form action`.

Also your SQL syntax for delete is incorrect. While deleting records from the database, you don't specify the columns. You delete the entire record.

The delete syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `method="post"` from your form so nothing is being posted, this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty clear.

```
$_POST['del']
```

doesn't exists since `del` isn't a valid field into the posted form.

If `del` is the name of checkboxes, you have first of all to retrive them by adding `post action` to your form